# Database layout for a comment upvote system in visual studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have a database running in SQL server that I can edit/add/ retrieve information from with no worries. I just have a question about the best way to lay out the database in this situation.

Say I have a database stored with the columns

Score, DateTime, Comment

but when I want to display the table to the user I want them to see a table that has

Ranking (just 1-25 or so), Score, Time Since, Comment

What is the best tool to use in visual studio to achieve this?

I have been trying to use GridView which I figured made sense but I have trouble creating the ranking column and the time since column. What is the best way to achieve this?

Also when I adjust some algorithm to sort the comments by score and time since, where do I put this? In the C# or is there some way to incorporate this into the database?

Thanks a lot for the help!!

EDIT: It's an ASP.NET web form application

Comment: What kind of application are you creating?  winforms, wpf, silverlight, asp.net web forms, mvc, web api spa?

Comment: ASP.NET web forms. I adjusted the main post. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Use SSRS (Reporting Service) and use the **TOP** filter in your grid.